# can we generate 16 bytes hash using bcrypt?

Tags: bcrypt

I am planning to use bcrypt library for hashing the password with a max length of 16 bytes, the standard bcrypt library is generating the hash of 31 bytes as per the below example:

$2a$12$SBdXpoExjoJBtyVS3GBbh.***VR4TlNWSrM0XRRDJjAw0fnw8TLhuDj6***

Is it possible to generate the shorter hash of 16 bytes by changing some configuration or macro?

I tried changing the macro BCRYPT_HASHSIZE to 16 and 32 but it is not working as expected.

Thank you,
Regards,
Shreyas.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to shorten the resulting hash.

You need to increase the size of your `varchar(50)` to `varchar(200)` to hold everything required.